# How to build socket io server in different file except app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am pretty new to node.js and now I am doing a project on building a website on node.js. Sorry if my question is very naive.

I am using express framework.
My app.js is listening at port (3000). 
In my route.js, I got some data from calling some API. I want to display the data to my datapoint.jade file. And because I want to draw those datapoint I have to embed a javascript file in jade. I want to use socket.io to achieve this sending and receiving data.
However, all the examples to construct socket is in app.js. I get data in router.js(in one of its callback function). app.js require router.js.
How can I send data from route.js to app.js and then send out to client side.

Could you please guide me some related and useful information? Or my design would not work at all?

Comment: Could you please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common paradigm is to pass any dependencies to your child modules:

```
// app.js
var socket = require('socket.io');
var app = require('express')();

var routes = require('./routes.js')(app, socket);
app.listen();

// routes.js
module.exports = function(app, socket){
  var routes = {};
  app.use('/', routes.handleIndex)
  socket.on('connection', function(){
    ...
  })
}
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you! I have tried it out and using socketio.js. It works like a charm!!!